# Are explicit roxygen import from base package needed?

Tags: r, r-package

Concrete example:

In my package, one of my functions uses `grep` form the `base` package.

Should I explicitly import `grep` or would that just introduce useless dependencies? I mean, everyone already has the `base` package, right?

For the sake of illustration:

```
#' Group_by with regex based column selection
#' Similar to `group_by` but grouping columns are selected with a regex.
#' @importFrom dplyr group_by
#' @importFrom base grep
#' @export
group_at <- function(df, pattern)
  group_by_(df, .dots=grep(names(df), pattern=pattern, value=T))
```

Comment: If you needed to import `grep`, you'd need to import everything, even `function` and `(`, which also live in base. That would become tedious pretty soon.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the *Writing R Extensions* manual sec.1.1.3:

> It makes no sense to declare a dependence on R without a version specification, nor on the package base: this is an R package and package base is always available.

Comment: Thanks! I actually discovered that roxygen throws an error message saying that `base` should not be imported. The package then fails to load because of an illegal NAMESPACE containing base (`asNamespace` :  `operation not allowed on base namespace`).

Answer (score 2):

By deleting  the following terms associated to the package `base` from NAMESPACE

```
  import(base)  , 
 importFrom(base,system.file)
```

and in the DESCRIPTION file, delete the following term.

```
 Imports: base
```

Then the following error vanished:

```
 preparing package for lazy loading
Error in asNamespace(ns, base.OK = FALSE) : 
  operation not allowed on base namespace
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'aa'
```

Comment: There is something odd going on here. I am writing a package that needs `month.abb`. RMD check then says: : no visible global function definition for ‘month.abb’
   Undefined global functions or variables:
     month.abb
   Consider adding
     importFrom("base", "month.abb")
   to your NAMESPACE file.